# Change values within a range avoiding loops, for speed

Tags: vba, loops, excel, find

I've got the following code that works very slowly. Any ideas on how to make faster?

Some background, in a previous Sub I had taken a range and then copy and pasted it. Now I need to change the values according to the code. Would it be possible to take this range and subject it to the modifications without pasting it first maybe?

```
Sub ChangeArea()
    Dim Book As Workbook
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim AreaRange As Range
    Dim LastRow
    Dim c As Range
    Set Book = Workbooks("Testing")
    Set Sheet = Book.Worksheets("Data")
    Sheet.Activate
    LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
    Set AreaRange = Sheet.Range("AG5:AG" & LastRow)
    For Each c In AreaRange.Cells
        If c.Value = "10" Then
            c.Value = "Mark"
        ElseIf c.Value = "will" Then
            c.Value = "William"
        ElseIf c.Value = "Uncle" Then
            c.Value = "Bill"
        ElseIf c.Value = "Roomate" Then
            c.Value = "Robert"
        Else: End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: One thing you can do is to put the highest frequency of matches first. If *Roomate* occurs the most frequently, it should be the first test for a match. Same with the second, third, etc most frequent matches. Changing to a `Select Case ... End Select` might also offer some improved efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option may be to use the `Replace` method on your range. See below and try to accommodate into your worksheet.

```
Sub ChangeThem()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("AG5:AG" & lRow)

    rng.Replace what:=1, replacement:="One"
    rng.Replace what:=2, replacement:="Two"
    rng.Replace what:=3, replacement:="Three"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do this first, make sure everything's working as intended, then apply Sobigen's tweak.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
```

to the top and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

to the bottom

This keeps the screen from updating on every change.